# Parse JSON array from URL

Tags: android, json, parsing

I have this JSON array:

```
[{"id":"101","title":"Oferta 1"},{"id":"102","title":"Oferta 2"},{"id":"103","title":"Oferta del Mes"},{"id":"104","title":"Promoci\u00f3n Facebook"}]
```

I need to parse this JSON, but when I parse it I recive only

```
{"id":"101","title":"Oferta 1"}
```

This is my code:

```
try {
    JSONObject json = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("URLOFJSON");
    Log.i("log_tag", json.toString()); 
    String jsonvalues =  json.getString("id");

    Log.i("log_tag", jsonvalues);  
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Log.e("log_tag", "Error getJSONfromURL "+ex.toString());           
}
```

How can I resolve this?

Thanks for all.

Comment: You're parsing your response as a JSONObject instead of a JSONArray.  Parse it as a JSONArray.

Comment: Don't know about your `JSONFunctions`, but looks as if you trying to put a json array into a json object. 
Isn't there something like: `JSONfunctions.getJSONArrayFromURL`?

Comment: hey use the code below, n if it works accept the answer

Comment: Hi, my problem was the JSONFunctions, this class don't had a getJSONArrayFromURL only has a getJSONObjectFromURL and obtain data was wrong, only obtain the first record

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are taking a jsonObject, take a json array and from that retrieve json objects
Dummy code

```
JSonArray ja;
int resultCount = ja.length();
for (int i = 0; i < resultCount; i++)
{
    JSONObject resultObject = ja.getJSONObject(i);
    String id = resultObject.getString("id");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

for getting the data from the json data use the following line of codes.

```
String my_info = investors.getProfileAbout(user_id).toString();
            LinearLayout about =(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.prof_about);
            about.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            try {
                JSONArray array = new JSONArray(my_info);
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject row = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    //id = row.getInt('id');
                    String type1 = row.getString("type");
                    String person_marks = row.getString("follwed");
                    String total_posts = row.getString("totalpost");
                    String componsated = row.getString("ipost");
                    String mods = row.getString("mods");
                    String  doj = row.getString("bday");

                    String avatar = row.getString("avatar");


                   TextView type = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mebership);
                   type.setText(type1);

                   TextView marks = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.marks);
                   marks.setText(person_marks);

                   TextView total_pos = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.total_posts);
                   total_pos.setText(total_posts);

                   TextView componsated_posts = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.componsated_posts);
                   componsated_posts.setText(componsated);

                   TextView moderating = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.moderating);
                   moderating.setText(mods);

                   TextView user_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.profile_username);
                   user_name.setText(extras.getString("user_name"));

                   ImageView userProfilePic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.user_profile_img);
                   userProfilePic.setImageBitmap(mySession.downloadImage(avatar));

                   TextView dob = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dob);
                    dob.setText(doj);
                }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Exception", "Exception when parsing response JSON."+e.getMessage());
                }
```

For more detail click here http://grabcodes.blogspot.com

Answer (score 0):

I solved with this code.

```
URL urlws = new URL(
                "URLOFFJSON");
        URLConnection tc = urlws.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                tc.getInputStream()));
        String line;

        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(line);
            for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) ja.get(i);
                Log.i("log_tag", jo.toString());
            }
        }
```

This way I can get the webservice JSONArray

Thanks for all